# Firefox transform style inside Javascript, is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, transition

Helloes..

**We have this HTML**

```
<div id="bz"></div>

<ul>
    <li onClick="black();">Black</li>
    <li onClick="brown();">Brown</li>
    <li onClick="red();">Red</li>
</ul>
```

**And this CSS:**

```
#bz{
  float:left;
  background-image:url('http://almakeramidi.gr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/keramidi.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:100%;
  width:417px;
  height:468px;
  transition:all 1s;
}
```

**Along with this bad-written JS:**

```
function black(){
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:0;";
document.getElementById('bz').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://almakeramidi.gr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/gkri.jpg')";
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:1;";
}

function brown(){
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:0;";
document.getElementById('bz').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://almakeramidi.gr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/kafe-1.jpg')";
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:1;";
}

function red(){
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:0;";
document.getElementById('bz').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://almakeramidi.gr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/kokkino-1.jpg')";
document.getElementById('bz').style.cssText += "opacity:1;";
}
```

Lets put them all in the [oven](http://codepen.io/dominotrix/pen/vLzjed).

Now, if you view it in Chrome, it smoothly transitions between the colors.

But if you view this in Firefox, smoothness gone!

Anyone knows why?

Many thanks!

Comment: Because the transition between background images is not implemented in Firefox [Bug 546052: Support CSS transitions with background-image images (cross-fade())](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I dont want to transition backgroud-image. I am trying to transition opacity to the whole div so it's invisible, then change the background-image and finally bring back the opacity to 1.

Comment: You don't queue up the the effects that way. You only set the opacity to `1` every time, the `0` will be overwritten immediately. The browser will use the final result of your modifications to `style`  and do a transition of the previous state to the new one.

Comment: Oh I get it.. So in JS,  opacity:0;opacity:1; will not trigger a transition. It will just return the last value as if it was only one.

Comment: I added an alert(); command  between the background-image and opacity, just to somehow pause the function. It seems to be working good in Firefox. Can I pause for .5s the function from running? Kinda like a delay.